# How to save all links from all pages to csv using python beautiful soup

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup

Am trying to save all links collected from multiple paginated pages to csv. from print(links) I can see all the links I want to save from multiple pages but unfortunately, when I open csv file, am only finding one URL save. How can I save all URLs I see from the terminal (print(links) to csv?

below is my code:

def scrape_pages(url) -> None:

```
#max_pages = 10

max_pages = 5 # doing 3 pages for examples sake

current_page = 1

# Loop through all pages dynamically and build the url using the page number suffix the website uses

while current_page <= max_pages:

    print(f'{url}page/{current_page}')

    # Get each page's html

    raw_html1 = requests.get(f'{url}page/{current_page}')

    soup1 = BeautifulSoup(raw_html1.text, 'html.parser')

    current_page += 1
   
   # Find all table rows and from each table row get the needed data 

    #root = 'https://wwwxxxxxx.com'

    
    for link1 in soup1.find_all('li',{'class':'xxx'}):

     link2 =  link1.find('a',href=True)

     link3 = 'https://www.xxxxxxx.com'+(link2['href'])

    links = []

    [links.append(link3) for link2 in link1 ]  
   


    for link2 in links:

        raw_html =  urlopen(link3)

        soup = BeautifulSoup(raw_html.read(), 'html.parser')


    def getTitle(soup):

      return soup.find('h2', class_="xxx").text.strip()

   
       
    with open('output.csv', 'w', encoding='utf8', newline='') as 
    f_output:

       csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)

       csv_output.writerow(['Title'])

       row = [getTitle(soup)]

       print(row)

       for f_output in row:

         csv_output.writerow(row)


   # print(product, row, Title)
  
    time.sleep(5) # sleep before scraping next page to not send too 
     many requests at once 
    
    print('\n\n') # Clearing console up
```

def main() -> int:

```
URL = 'https://www.xxxxxx.com/'

scrape_pages(URL)

return 0
```

if **name** == '**main**':
exit(main())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import time as t

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36'}

s = requests.Session()
s.headers.update(headers)

links_list = []
for x in range(1, 3):
    r = s.get(f'https://www.myjobmag.com/page/{x}')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    links = soup.select_one('ul.job-list').select('li.job-list-li')
    for link in links:
        try:
            title = link.select_one('h2').text.strip()
            url = link.select_one('h2').select_one('a').get('href')
            r = s.get(f'https://www.myjobmag.com{url}')
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
            key_info = soup.select_one('ul.job-key-info').text.strip()
            description = soup.select_one('div.job-details').text.strip()
            application_method = soup.select_one('div.mag-b.bm-b-30').text.strip()
            
            links_list.append((title, key_info, description, application_method, url))
            print(f'done {title} -- {url}')
            t.sleep(5)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

df = pd.DataFrame(links_list, columns = ['title', 'key_info', 'description', 'application_method', 'url'])
df.to_csv('my_wonderful_jobs_list.csv')
```

This will return a csv file with job title, key info, description, application method, and url.

Comment: hi @platipus thanks for the answer but am a newbie may you kindly write the full code. what method should I use for page?

Comment: You write functions with type hints. How are you a newbie? Did you write that code in the original question?

Comment: Well, I just mix codes from here and other different forums. The code above i copied from a tutorial and infused my own things. please me on what method i should use for page.

Comment: Updated my response with full code...

Comment: great thanks it has worked. I would like to update the question from the collected urls, i want to scrape some data

Comment: i have modified the question.

Comment: i dont know how to accept the answer

Comment: I updated my answer, based on your new requirements. You accept an answer by clicking the checkmark under the vote arrows.

Comment: Hi, its giving error: probably add box

Comment: That's not an error, mate: that is printing when going over empty `li` elements, reserved for adverts.

Comment: It's right there: `description = soup.select_one('div.job-details').text.strip()`, added to csv file.

Comment: StackOverFlow is not a code writing service. You would need to hire someone for that.